# Why may a matrix be singular or ill-conditioned with standard learning algorithm for linear classification?

Tags: machine-learning, least-squares, singular-matrix

In the learning algorithm for linear classification by least square method, which find a weight vector $\hat w\in R^d$ and bias $\hat b\in R$ for a linear scoring function $f(x) = \hat w ^T x +\hat b$ for which may write the solution for $\hat w =[\sum^n_{i=1}(x_i-\bar x)(x_i -\bar x)^T]^{-1}\sum^n_{i=1}(x_i-\bar x)(x_i -\bar x)$, why may the matrix $\sum^n_{i=1}(x_i-\bar x)(x_i -\bar x)^T$ be singular or ill-conditioned ? What does that mean to be ill-conditioned ? why does it occurs when $n$ is less than the dimension of $x$ ?

Comment: This question seems answerable directly from definitions. A matrix is singular if it is not full rank. A matrix is ill-conditioned if it has a high condition number.

Comment: @Sycorax Yes but how may $\sum^n_{i=1}(x_i-\bar x)(x_i -\bar x)$ be singular or ill-conditioned? What issues does it imply so that the standard learning algorithm may not be computable then ?

Comment: The expression you've written in your comment is not a matrix, just a sum of scalar products, so the concepts of singularity don't apply. Did you mean to include a transpose? If so, you should consult Mark L Stone's answer.

Comment: @Sycorax, there is a missing ^T typo in the last occurrence of that in the original question.  I answered as though the typo hadn't occurred.

Comment: @Sycorax, I've taken the liberty of inserting the missing ^T in the OP's question.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Thank you. I had mentally filled in the $~^\top$ when reading the question, but when the error was repeated in the comment I thought it best to ask for clarification.

Comment: Yes ! The $T$ is missing in my comment above !
Sorry if I am not that active, I am still trying to figure the answer out. I'm so bad and slow ind understanding maths ! I'm only a computer scientist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sum^n_{i=1}(x_i-\bar x)(x_i -\bar x)^T$ is a $d$ by $d$ matrix, where $x$ is a $d$ by $1$ vector.

For each $i$, $(x_i-\bar x)(x_i -\bar x)^T$ is a $d$ by $d$ matrix.  This matrix is rank one, because it is the outer product of a vector with itself.  $\sum^n_{i=1}(x_i-\bar x)(x_i -\bar x)^T$ is the sum of $n$ rank one matrices, and therefore has a rank not exceeding $n$.  If $n < d$, $\sum^n_{i=1}(x_i-\bar x)(x_i -\bar x)^T$ must therefore be singular, because it can not be of full rank k.

In a sense, singular is the most ill-conditioned a matrix can be, having condition number = $\infty$.  Even if $\sum^n_{i=1}(x_i-\bar x)(x_i -\bar x)^T$ is not singular, which can only be the case if $n \ge d$, it may still be ill-conditioned, thereby resulting in numerically unstable and very sensitive calculations when it is inverted or used in a linear system of equations. There are shrinkage estimators (search on this site and on the internet) to try to improve the conditioning of (sample) covariance matrices.  $\sum^n_{i=1}(x_i-\bar x)(x_i -\bar x)^T$ is the sample covariance matrix, other than not dividing by $n$ or $n-1$; note that dividing by $n$ or $n-1$ does not affect the rank vs not dividing at all.